# LINQ DB List Contains Object

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a linq query, but it doesn't work. My DB consists of a EventDetails Table from where I get the Student, then I want to get foreach Student the Class (n:1). So I iterate the Class Table and check if the List of Students contains the Student. What am I doing wrong?

The Code:

```
var students = db.EventDetails
    .Include("Room")
    .Include("Task")
    .Include("Student")
    .Where(x => x.Student != null)
    .Select(x => x);

foreach (var s in students)
{
    string studentClass = db.Class
    .Include("Students")
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.Students.Contains(s.Student))
    .Select(x => x.Name).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving the output you've shown because you're calling `ToString()` on an `IEnumerable<string>` instead, use `String.Join` to get the expected result, i.e.

```
 string studentClass = string.Join(", ",db.Class
        .Include("Students")       
        .Where(x => x.Students.Contains(s.Student))
        .Select(x => x.Name));
```

Also, calling `.ToList()` in the middle of the query is unnecessary and causes avoidable overhead, so it's better not to call it there at all.

Comment: How does `x.Students.Contains(s.Student)` properly translate to sql shouldn't you need to filter it by the studentId?

Comment: @johnny5 The issue at hand was more concerned about the output as opposed to what the Linq query translates to SQL.